# Error: Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView - ProgressDialog

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

hey I get this error mentioned in the header.

I have a `Handler` which looks every 100ms if the right command is sending over bluetooth. And if this command appears it is doing some stuff and then the `ProgressDialog` should close with `endBookingPD.dismiss();` After closing the Dialog the Handler should be removed with `lookForCommandHandler.removeCallbacks(tCommand);`

So this works for me the first time I click the button. But at the second time it gives me the mentioned error ond this line `endBookingPD.show();`

I searched on some questioned on this topic which already exit, but I didn't find a solution for my problem.

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks in Advance.

**Here's my code:**

```
btnEndBooking.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

endBookingPD=new ProgressDialog(CheckVehicleActivity.this);
endBookingPD.setMessage(ss1);
endBookingPD.show();
endBookingPD.setCancelable(true);

lookForCommandHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
tCommand = new Thread() {
public void run() {

MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();

if(driveOk != null){
if(driveOk.contains(DRIVE_EXIT_OK)){

// DOING SOME STUFF  

exitDrive = true;

if(exitDrive == true){
  if(endBookingPD != null){
   endBookingPD.dismiss();
  }
}

viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);

lookForCommandHandler.removeCallbacks(tCommand);
 }
}

if(exitDrive == false){
lookForCommandHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
}

System.out.println("Look for Msg Handler Running!!!!!");

tCommand.start(); 
});
```

**Log:**

```
10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509): Activity   
com.example.amvcarsharingkit.CheckVehicleActivity has leaked window 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41af8978 that was originally 
added here
10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
com.example.amvcarsharingkit.CheckVehicleActivity has leaked window
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41af8978 that was originally
added here
10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):     
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>
(ViewRootImpl.java:348)

 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at

 com.example.amvcarsharingkit.CheckVehicleActivity$10$1.onClick(
 CheckVehicleActivity.java:80   1)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(
 AlertController.java:168)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4464)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:589)
 10-31 08:28:13.329: E/WindowManager(14509):    at 
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
 Method)
```

Comment: did u find the answer? i am facing similar problem @aut_silvia

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290121/android-view-windowleaked-while-using-dialog-new-intent